# Why isn't strptime not working in my code?

Tags: python, django, datetime, strptime

I am using the following piece of code to populate my database. I've imported `from datetime import datetime` and is trying to create a datetime object to save to the DateTimeField of django.

```
with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media', 'attendance', 'populate.csv')) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            obj, created = Attendance.objects.get_or_create(
                employee_id=row[0],
                punch=datetime.strptime(row[1], "%Y%m%d %H%M"),
                )
```

This is the error that I get.

```
ValueError at /attn/populate/
time data ' 20170604 0600' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H%M'
```

It seems like the string DOES match the format. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The string is `' 20170604 0600'`, note the leading whitespace.

Change the format to `' %Y%m%d %H%M'`, or use `strip` to remove any leading or trailing spaces from the string:

```
for row in reader:
            obj, created = Attendance.objects.get_or_create(
                employee_id=row[0],
                punch=datetime.strptime(row[1].strip(), "%Y%m%d %H%M"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Extra leading space in string

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.strptime(" 20170604 0600", " %Y%m%d %H%M"))
print(datetime.strptime("20170604 0600", "%Y%m%d %H%M"))
```